# How can I find all sites aligned to a Hub where I have permissions in modern search webpart v4

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, kql

I'am using the Modern Search Webpart v.4 in SP Online.
I want to search all SharePoint sites which are created from template GROUP, assigned to this site which is a hub. If possible also show only if I have permissions on this site.

I have tried the following after research but it's not working:

SiteTiel:{searchTerms} SiteTemplate:GROUP AND DepartmentID:{{PageContext.hubSiteId}}

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

On the Site set the refinement filter to:

```
contentclass:STS_Site AND DepartmentId =f9f300f4-5df0-4564-b71f-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Because only to the hub assigned sites where I have permissions are displayed it meets my requirements.